# unittest passing along session

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

Writing some unit tests for a API I am busy with, trying to set a session in my unit test to simulate users that's already logged in. 
For some reason it does not look like the session get's passed along to the api endpoint through client.get. Anyone got any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
    client = app.test_client()
    with client.session_transaction() as sess:
        sess['username'] = 'bob@example.com'
        response = client.get('/users/')

        # Looks good 
        # <SecureCookieSession {'username': 'bob@example.com'}>
        print sess

        # Nothing in the cookie...
        print response.data 

        # self.assertEquals(
        #     json.loads(response.data),
        #     json.loads('{"users": "all"}'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the `client.get()` *out* of the `with` context manager:

```
with app.test_client() as client:
    with client.session_transaction() as sess:
        sess['username'] = 'bob@example.com'

    response = client.get('/users/')
```

The session 'committed' at the end of the `with` block only.